# How to handle common css code in html without using external linking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have almost 20 html pages with common css code in all the web pages. I made a single file of all these 20 html pages. Each html page has internal css code which is common in all the pages. I need to dump this single file(combination of 20 html pages) into the serial flash of my embedded device. I would like to make css code common for all the 20 pages but I don't want to do it using external linkage. Is there is any way to do this if possible could any one suggest it. It would be good if it could be done using javascript or jquery.This problem will reduce the size of my single file which saves my flash memory.Please anyone could help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That looks like a broad question.

Comment: yes,but I don't know whether it sounds correct or not..

Comment: Why don't you want to use external linking?

Comment: If I use external linking I need to create separate css file and I need to read the css file data from serial flash which makes my work more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Does the embedded device use a webserver to serve up the page? If so does the webserver support [Server Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) (SSI) or scripting via perl or PHP etc? If so you can use those technologies to include the common CSS (or any HTML), and the webpage will be sent to the client with the common CSS included.

Another option is to really have a single web page and use HTML anchors in a fixed menu to let the user jump to certain points in the single page and have them appear to be chapters.

Comment: No I don't have any webserver support server side Includes or scripting via perl or PHP. Let me try with your second option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use css code within your file, even with reduced size then you can minify your CSS code. Try to minify your css code in :

https://cssminifier.com/

If you want overall reduced size then you can follow these points:

1. minify css as mentioned above.
2. minify js on https://javascript-minifier.com/
3. Reduce image size. i.e. resize heavy size images with less size.
4. Reduce unwanted loops in the code.

Comment: Thank you but my code is getting completely compressed and styling of my page got completely changed. It is not as I expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can append your CSS

```
 $('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" />');
```

or have to give single element CSS like

```
$("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
```

Here `p` is *selector/class/id*